# How to change project name

Tags: jakarta-ee, pentaho

I want to rename my pentaho project name. Lets suppose my project is deployed as

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/login
```

but i want to rename pentaho as

```
http://localhost:8080/myname/login
```

How can i do it?

Comment: How your project looks like? Do you have web.xml? Probably you can change context-root of your application to achive your goal.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. The project structure that you have in eclipse or any IDE, actually replicated within the server on deployment. So all you need to do is rename the project and deploy. You can access with the new URL. A word of caution, the **context-root**, in the deployment decriptor will not change.